# Pandas Dataframe Time Duration Expand to Minute Data

Tags: python, pandas, time, aggregate, duration

I am receiving data which consists of a 'StartTime' and a 'Duration' of time active. This is hard to work with when I need to do calculations on a specified time range over multiple days. I would like to break this data down to minutely data to make future calculations easier. Please see the example to get a better understanding.

Data which I currently have:

```
data = {'StartTime':['2018-12-30 12:45:00+11:00','2018-12-31 16:48:00+11:00','2019-01-01 04:36:00+11:00','2019-01-01 19:27:00+11:00','2019-01-02 05:13:00+11:00'],
        'Duration':[1,1,3,1,2],
        'Site':['1','2','3','4','5']    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime']).dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Melbourne')
```

What I would like to have:

```
data_expected = {'Time':['2018-12-30 12:45:00+11:00','2018-12-31 16:48:00+11:00','2019-01-01 04:36:00+11:00','2019-01-01 04:37:00+11:00','2019-01-01 19:27:00+11:00','2019-01-02 05:13:00+11:00','2019-01-02 05:14:00+11:00'],
        'Duration':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        'Site':['1','2','3','3','4','5','5']    
}

df_expected = pd.DataFrame(data_expected)
df_expected['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_expected['Time']).dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Melbourne')
```

I would like to see if anyone has a good solution for this problem. Effectively, I would need data rows with Duration >1 to be duplicated with time +1minute for each minute above 1 minute duration. Is there a way to do this without creating a whole new dataframe?

******** EDIT ********

In response to @DavidErickson 's answer. Putting this here because I can't put images in comments. I ran into a bit of trouble. df1 is a subset of the original dataframe. df2 is df1 after applying the code provided. You can see that the time that is added on to index 635 is incorrect.
[image: Comparison dataframes]

Comment: the syntax for this part of the code `.dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Melbourne')` was not working for me. You can use my answer and figure out the syntax as the final step to convert to another timezone.

Comment: Cann duration be greater than 2?

Comment: @jlandercy yes, it can be greater than 2

Comment: @DavidErickson sorry, that's my mistake. I changed the column name from "StartTime" to "Time" in df_expected, to try to highlight the change in time data. I will edit to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.index.repeat` according to the `Duration` column to add the relevant number of rows. Then create a mask with `.groupby` and `cumcount` that adds the appropriate number of minutes on top of the base time.

input:

```
data = {'StartTime':['2018-12-30 12:45:00+11:00','2018-12-31 16:48:00+11:00','2019-01-01 04:36:00+11:00','2019-01-01 19:27:00+11:00','2019-01-02 05:13:00+11:00'],
        'Duration':[1,1,2,1,2],
        'Site':['1','2','3','4','5']    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])
```

code:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Duration'])]
mask = df.groupby('Site').cumcount()
df['StartTime'] = df['StartTime'] + pd.to_timedelta(mask, unit='m')
df = df.append(df).sort_values('StartTime').assign(Duration=1).drop_duplicates()
df
```

output:

```
    StartTime                   Duration    Site
0   2018-12-30 12:45:00+11:00   1           1
1   2018-12-31 16:48:00+11:00   1           2
2   2019-01-01 04:36:00+11:00   1           3
2   2019-01-01 04:37:00+11:00   1           3
2   2019-01-01 04:38:00+11:00   1           3
3   2019-01-01 19:27:00+11:00   1           4
4   2019-01-02 05:13:00+11:00   1           5
4   2019-01-02 05:14:00+11:00   1           5
```

If you are running into memory issues, then you can also try with `dask`. I have included @jlandercy's pandas answer and changed to `dask` syntax as I'm not sure if the pandas operation `index.repeat` would work with `dask`. Here is documentation on the funcitons/operations. I would research the ones in the code https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
#read as a dask dataframe from csv or SQL or other
df = dd.read_csv(files) #df = dd.read_sql_table(table, uri, index_col='StartTime')
df['offset'] = df['Duration'].apply(lambda x: list(range(x)))
df = dd.explode('offset')
df['offset'] = df['offset'].apply(lambda x: dd.Timedelta(x, unit='T'))
df['StartTime'] += df['offset']
df["Duration"] = 1
```

Comment: I have asked precision to the OP, we also need to address use case where Duration > 2.

Comment: I get the following error: ```ValueError: invalid timedelta unit min provided```

Comment: @meronpan you must be on a different version. Try `'minute'` or `'minutes'` instead of `'min'`

Comment: @DavidErickson thanks ``` unit='m' ``` works for me. Unfortunately, it seems this code does not work for duration>2. Please refer to the revised question where a duration value of 3 is used.

Comment: Aah, I interpreted your question another way. I will try to revise

Comment: @meronpan , I took a different approach which should solve now.

Comment: @DavidErickson thanks for taking the time to revise the answer. This works perfectly. Will give it a go on the whole set of data. :)

Comment: Just to give an update. I tried running this code on the full dataframe (35572813 rows) and got memory error. I should've mentioned in the original post that it is a very big database. I think my solution will be to divide the full dataframe into smaller manageable chunks for this code to apply to. Then afterwards join the multiple dataframes together.

Comment: @meronpan, yes definitely try chunking with pandas first. Alternatively, `dask` is amazing when you are running into  memory limitations. Not too bad of a learning curve if you are good with pandas. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @DavidErickson Hi David, sorry to bother you again. I managed to grab out a subset of data and apply your code on to it. Please refer to the bottom of my original post for an edit showing what is happening. Is this due to some sort of error on my end? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to address use case where `Duration > 2` as well.

For the modified given input:

```
data = {'StartTime':['2018-12-30 12:45:00+11:00','2018-12-31 16:48:00+11:00','2019-01-01 04:36:00+11:00','2019-01-01 19:27:00+11:00','2019-01-02 05:13:00+11:00'],
        'Duration':[1,1,3,1,2],
        'Site':['1','2','3','4','5']    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])
```

This code should do the trick:

```
df['offset'] = df['Duration'].apply(lambda x: list(range(x)))
df = df.explode('offset')
df['offset'] = df['offset'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, unit='T'))
df['StartTime'] += df['offset']
df["Duration"] = 1
```

Basically, it works as follow:

- create a list of integer based on Duration value;
- replicate row (`explode`) with consecutive integer offset;
- transform integer offset into `timedelta` offset;
- perform `datetime` arithmetics and reset Duration field.

The result is about:

```
                  StartTime  Duration Site   offset
0 2018-12-30 12:45:00+11:00         1    1 00:00:00
1 2018-12-31 16:48:00+11:00         1    2 00:00:00
2 2019-01-01 04:36:00+11:00         1    3 00:00:00
2 2019-01-01 04:37:00+11:00         1    3 00:01:00
2 2019-01-01 04:38:00+11:00         1    3 00:02:00
3 2019-01-01 19:27:00+11:00         1    4 00:00:00
4 2019-01-02 05:13:00+11:00         1    5 00:00:00
4 2019-01-02 05:14:00+11:00         1    5 00:01:00
```

Comment: I get the following error: ``` AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode' ```

Comment: @meronpan you are probably on an older version of pandas and consider updating. Only newer version of pandas have explode.

Comment: @meronpan, Consider using: `python -m pip install -U pandas` to upgrade. Cheers

Comment: Thanks guys. This is a very annoying issue as it seems like you've got the solution for me, but my Pandas is not up to date. I'm currently using my work PC so upgrading Pandas is not so easy. Will try to get this to work. Cheers

Comment: @meronpan, then use `python -m pip install -U --user pandas` instead. Definitely upgrade your pandas, you are missing important features. Cheers